Stability analysis in LTspice breaks down with biased non-inverting input
I've been playing around with stability analysis in LTspice using the large L and C method. I've noticed that the simulation breaks down with a small bias voltage on the non-inverting input. Changing from a dual supply to a single supply may also break the analysis and it seems to be dependent on the opamp SPICE model as well.
I don't have a full understanding of the large L and C method so I might be missing something. Do I need to connect the non-inverting input to ground? What are the mandatory prerequisites for successfully performing a stability analysis with this method?
Below are the test circuit I've used and analysis waveforms for 0 V bias and 1 V bias.
Edit: I should have plotted VOP, which is the loop gain, and not VOUT.




Added below after comments.
Maybe easier to look at a scaled down circuit. Below is same circuit as in the LTSpice video. First waveform with 0 V bias. Second with 7 V bias.
Edit:
I got a little lost during my simulations and made the mistake to show an example circuit (top in this post) with a high gain. In this case, even a small bias will break the stability analysis since the output will be saturated to the rail voltage.
As pointed out by Raonoke in the comment below, an analysis will fail even for the below test circuit when the bias is 7 V since it will drive the output too close to the rail.
In my initial tests, not shown here, the stability analysis (using the large L and C method) broke down even with a small bias voltage that didn't saturate the output. So what I've failed to bring about is that the large L and C method seems to have a problem with a bias voltage. When using this method on the below circuit, even a bias voltage of only 100 mV breaks the analysis. Unless I've made another mistake...



asc. file:
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 128 -16 -16 -16
WIRE 320 -16 208 -16
WIRE -144 0 -144 -32
WIRE 192 80 192 48
WIRE 192 96 192 80
WIRE -16 112 -16 -16
WIRE 0 112 -16 112
WIRE 32 112 0 112
WIRE 128 112 112 112
WIRE 160 112 128 112
WIRE -144 128 -144 80
WIRE -144 128 -256 128
WIRE 256 128 224 128
WIRE 320 128 320 -16
WIRE 320 128 256 128
WIRE 384 128 320 128
WIRE -16 144 -16 112
WIRE 160 144 112 144
WIRE -256 160 -256 128
WIRE -144 176 -144 128
WIRE 112 176 112 144
WIRE 192 192 192 160
WIRE 192 208 192 192
WIRE -16 272 -16 224
WIRE -144 288 -144 256
WIRE 112 288 112 256
FLAG -16 272 0
FLAG 192 80 vcc
FLAG 256 128 VOP
FLAG 384 128 VOUT
FLAG 0 112 FB
FLAG -256 160 0
FLAG -144 -32 vcc
FLAG -144 288 vee
FLAG 192 192 vee
FLAG 112 288 0
FLAG 128 112 INM
SYMBOL res -32 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 224 -32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage -144 -16 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VCC
SYMATTR Value 15
SYMBOL voltage -144 160 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VEE
SYMATTR Value 15
SYMBOL voltage 112 160 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 0 -48 102 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName VB
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL voltage 16 112 R270
WINDOW 0 25 23 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 52 88 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 77 55 VBottom 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMBOL OpAmps\\LT6016 192 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
TEXT 192 248 Left 2 !.ac dec 100 0.1 10Meg


I think your loop gain circuitry contains an error: The lowpass R3-C2 is not part of the loop - hence, you must use the output node of the opamp and NOT the node labelled as Vout.

Yes, you're correct. I also noticed that and have commented on it.

With the scaled down circuit based on LT6016 and a bias voltage of 7V you are again way to close to the positive rail. Reduce the bias voltage in 0.1V steps and at a certain level the loop gain and phase plot will be back to normal.

You're absolutely right. I've made som mistakes and failed to convey that the problem with the analysis breaking down with a small bias in my initial tests, not posted here, seems to be the large L and C method. I've tried to clarify this in my original post.

@FreddaH core of the issue is the position from where you are injecting the signal. Use a replica or just go with my simpler recommendation as I pointed out in my edited answer.

The Issues In Your Simulation Setup
There are 2 issues in your simulation setup:

Bias voltage in the (+) terminal is too high that it causes the op-amp to saturate -> spoiled operating point.
The injection of an AC signal at the output node for loop gain simulation purposes via the LC method requires a replica circuit.

About the bias voltage
100mV in that V3 times your gain would already give you the 10V towards the output, and that's probably not even possible even if the opamp is rail-to-rail. Your amplifier is being driven out of its linear region
About the LC method and the need for a replica circuit
The reason for the huge capacitor is to prevent the voltage source disturbing the DC. The inductor, on the other hand, is a short at DC, so the operating point is kept, but opens the loop at AC, therefore the excitation and return values of the loop gain are measured at its terminals.
Unfortunately, even though the loop is open and the operating points are correct at DC, at AC the loop was seeing a feedback resistor of 1k; with the inductor now it sees an open. Due to this reason, a replica circuit is needed.
How to add a replica to the LC loop gain method
To begin, the first schematic, as drawn, is not good enough to get an accurate loop gain simulation. It even fails at low frequencies. The basic reason is:
The Op-Amp output still wants to see 1k, but instead, it sees an open due to the inductor.
This disturbs the loop, and thus it fails at low frequencies (it says that the pole is in the 1mHz range rather than 1Hz range).
To fix this we add a replica as in the picture below.

If we simulate the schematic above, you'll get a more accurate Loop Gain simulation (as shown below). The very low-frequency part is due to the LC, and the high-frequency dips are simulation artifacts (I believe), just ignored them for now.

However, this is very inconvenient and it's not entirely accurate.
The voltage source method from Middlebrook also has shortcomings
Mind you, the voltage stimuli I recommended before will also suffer from the same problem if you use it in that output node (see schm below) .
Even though this doesn't look like an open, it still is. The rule for this voltage source is that the return node impedance ((-) terminal of the voltage source) must be several orders magnitude lower than the controlled node ((+) terminal of the voltage source).
Another way to see this is that no AC current must running through the voltage source in the Middlebrook method.
If you increase the 1k feedback resistance to a much higher value, like 1Meg or 100Meg, then the loop gain will start being accurate. Unfortunately, such huge resistor times the bias current will inevitably disturb the original DC, therefore, you're going to see a different response compared to the 1k situation.
The most accurate loop gain response for most analog designs is with using both V and I sources, as shown in the paper from Middlebrook
If you insist that you want to place a probe at the output, then you can either use the replica, or do 2 subsequent runs with V and I sources, which also shown in the Middlebrook's 1975 paper Measurement of loop gain in feedback systems. However, this a little more complicated, as the loop gain is given by:
$$
L_{true} = \frac{L_vL_i-1}{L_v + L_i +2}
$$
In the paper I cited above there's the proof to this formula, it's not that hard. What's more cumbersome though is the 2 runs you have to do and write out the formula to plot it. I did this and found that the loop gains were identical even if we put the probe at the input or output.

Conclusion
To conclude, one has to go through a lot of trouble to get the right loop gain depending on which node one decides to inject the test signal. For that reason, I'd recommend you to just keep using the voltage source in series with the input. This complies (for the most part of the frequency, with perhaps some error near the UGF) with the rules of the having a low impedance left node and high impedance right node.
This simple voltage source method is shown in this LTspice video . It is the Middlebrook method published by him in 1975 (even though the video doesn't say it), but only using one source.
If you want to be as accurate as possible, I suggest to use the V-I probe. Even though that doesn't even account for reverse transmission (it assumes that the loop gain moves in one way only), it's good enough for most analog designs.

There is also an example (LoogGain.asc) in the example folder for LTspice that covers the method discussion in Middlebrook, R.D., "Measurement of Loop Gain in Feedback Systems", Int. J. Electronics, vol 38, No. 4, pp. 485-512, 1975.

@periblepsis indeed! Thanks for mentioning the full paper title.

I see typos in what I wrote. The file is LoopGain. The paper is cited in that file. I just copied it from there since the year matched your own. I'll be getting a copy to study, tomorrow.

@periblepsis for your reference, the main idea is also cited in the Fast Analytical Techniques by Vatche Vorperian as an exercise. The answer is in the paper you mentioned . The end objective of the method is to combine a voltage and current AC sources such that the "probe" can be placed around the loop without caring for the left and right equivalent impedance when using only a V or an I source.

Same comment here as in other answer. Yes, you're right. Should have checked that. However, even with changing resistors so that the gain is 5 I get the same break down behaviour. Also, I should have plotted VOP for displaying the loop gain and not VOUT.

@FreddaH What bias value were you using?

It breaks down with only 100 mV bias with gain of 5. Also, I've seen the video you've linked to and when testing that method it works with a bias of 500 mV.

@FreddaH difficult to debug with such little detail. Can you share the schematic?

Edited the question to include the LTSpice video example as a better starting point for the stability discussion.

@FreddaH I meant to say to share the contents of the .asc file, so that it's easy to reproduce what you're seeing.

Content of asc. file added.

Many thanks for a long and detailed explanation! The LC method goes in the trash in favor of the "voltage source in series with the input" method!

Putting 1v on the non-inverting input will cause the amplifier to saturate as you have it set to a gain of 101. Once saturated the AC characteristics will not be meaningful.
Putting a few millivolts on the input providing it does not force the opamp out of the linear region shouldn't have any significant AC effects.
If you change to a single supply you also need to ensure that the DC operating conditions are correct before you can analyze any AC characteristics.

Yes, you're right. Should have checked that. However, even with changing resistors so that the gain is 5 I get the same break down behaviour. Also, I should have plotted VOP for displaying the loop gain and not VOUT.

OK - you have reduced the gain down to "5" - but at which bias voltage at the non-inv. input? More than that, what is the purpose of this DC voltage?

The purpose of the bias voltage is to adapt the signal to an ADC stage and the plan is also to operate the opamp in single supply mode.
